# Opta Planner time format and conversion

Tags: optaplanner

We are building a solution to optimize crew, we start  working in opta with time window but i don't know the format of time.

What is actually the format of time in optaPlanner (Service time and due start time) and how i can Implement time conversion between java and C#??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OptaPlanner implementation of the use case. Normally, you'd use `java.time.*` classes on the Java/DRL side to accurately deal with timezones etc in your constraints.

As for bridging Java and C#, just connect through a REST service and use the standard ISO format (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) in the JSON or XML input/output.